# Concrete 5.7database query documentation

Tags: concrete5-5.7

New to concrete and trying to find some consistent doc on how to do insert, delete, update, etc. Docs say it follows doctrine\dbal, which is I read correclty should look like this:

$db = \Database::connection();
$db->insert('user', array('username' => 'jwage'));

But I haven't gotten that to work. Digging through the code I find it being done like this,

```
$db->execute('INSERT INTO gift_cert (bname) values(?)',
array($CardHoldersName)
);
```

Which does work, is this the new way, or the old way. Does someone have a link to docs that show all the possible commands and format somewhere? I can't seem to find it  in the API docs.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This doc outlines how to connect to the database and which methods are available:

https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/appendix/concrete5-version-8-coding-styles/database